# Is the triforce graph an sp-graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the examples and the statements

[image]

where a *series-parallel graph* (sp-graph) is defined inductively with respect to series composition and parallel composition of other sp-graphs or of $K_2$. I guess the former is not an sp-graph but I am unable to prove this, and I am also unable to prove the latter not to be an sp-graph.

Is the triforce graph a sp-graph, and how do you prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this alternative characterization of *series-parallel graphs* paraphrased from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_graph#Alternative_definition).

> **Definition:** A graph is an *sp-graph* if it may be turned into $K_2$ by a sequence of the following operations:
>
> 1. Replacement of a pair of parallel edges with a single edge that connects their common endpoints.
> 2. Replacement of a pair of edges incident to a vertex of degree $2$ other than the *initial* vertex or *terminal* vertex with a single edge.

Note that this characterization of sp-graphs is basically just the inductive definition considered backwards.

The $K_4$ is not an sp-graph because (1) there are no parallel edges to reduce, and (2) given any choice of initial and terminal vertices, there are no degree $2$ vertices to replace with an edge, so the algorithm given by this definition terminates.

The triforce, though, is an sp-graph. If you take any two of the degree-$4$ vertices as your initial and terminal vertex, you can apply (2) to the three degree-$2$ vertices, then apply (1) to the three resulting parallel edges to arrive at a triangle. Then you apply (2) once more and (1) once more and you have $K_2$.

Comment: Are you sure that the triforce is not an sp-graph? I can construct it with series and parallel operations so it should be an sp-graph. I will show later if clarification needed :)

Comment: @hhh, yeah, you're right. The triforce *is* an sp-graph. I thought a bit too hastily when I answered this question. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: How would you call "triforce graph" in academic paper? Assume you have get exactly the same graph as a deduction. Can you be more specific about the sp-graph?

Comment: @Masi, I'm not sure exactly what you are asking in your comment.

Comment: @MikePierce Triforce graph is the name in Legend of Zelda, I think. I think it would be better to use some mathematical systematic naming for such a thing. I think sp-graph is too open.

Comment: @Masi, it doesn't really matter. You could just put a picture of the graph in your paper and say something like "Let $G$ be the graph in figure (...)." Or you could call it an inscribed triangular graph. Or you could reference [Sierpinski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle) somehow.